# Issues installing Geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, geopandas

I tried `pip install geopandas`

When I run that, I get this error:

```
Collecting geopandas
  Using cached geopandas-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (962 kB)
Collecting pyproj>=2.2.0
  Using cached pyproj-2.6.1.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (17.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23.0 in c:\users\ryans\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geopandas) (1.0.1)
Collecting fiona
  Using cached Fiona-1.8.17.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\ryans\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ryans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cw2z1439\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ryans\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cw2z1439\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ryans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cw2z1439\fiona\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\ryans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cw2z1439\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I also tried `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

In this case, everything runs fine, but when I try to run this one-liner:

```
import geopandas as gpd
```

I get this result:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
```

I'm guessing that there is some kind of conflict with some other library that is installed, but it's just a guess, and I don't know for sure what the problem is.  How can I get this thing to work?  Thanks!!

Comment: you need to install all the dependencies first, [installation documentation](https://geopandas.org/install.html) will help you

Comment: I did that, even before posting my question.  Is there something else, perhaps?  It seems like other people can use this library, but it does not work for me.

Comment: well if your colleagues can usethe library then i suggest you to ask them for all the package they installed and you can install it with same version

Comment: Well, I work by myself now; I am employee number one, of one. I don't have any colleagues whatsoever, but I saw some posts online that seem to work for other people, supposedly. This thing does not work for me. Anyway, thanks for trying to help me out.

Comment: Probably not so helpful, but installing geopandas in windows with Anaconda is a bit of a nightmare. I succeeded in the end but unfortunately I did not document how I did it. Not sure if relevant but I do have a User variable `GDAL` in my Environment Variables with the value  `C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\envs\geo-env\Lib\site-packages\osgeo`. Trial and error will probably get you there.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
$ conda install -c anaconda pip
$ pip install geopandas
$ pip install Fiona
```

Comment: None of that worked CamXiMuoi, but thanks for trying to help me out.  Is there another library out there that does similar things as geopandas?

Answer (score 0):

For me this installation worked (even without Anaconda).
Get the GDAL package from [here (Gohlke)](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

Install it with `pip install GDAL_..._.whl`

Upon installing the same error will occur, but no problem!
Go to the system environment variables and create a new system variable and name it `GDAL_VERSION` and give it the value of the package version. Looks like this:

[image: GDAL Environment variable]

Then try to install GDAL again and it will work (maybe you need to restart the console).
Then install geopandas with `pip install geopandas` and everything should work.